# no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer, Ruby

Tags: ruby, implicit-conversion

I am new to ruby, and have no idea, how to fix this error. when i run my script containing the code below, i always get the error: 'no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer. I think the Problem is in the lines @killProc..., @Name=..., and @working_directory.
Can you tell me whats wrong?

Thanks for your help

```
class RubyCommand
      include Patir::Command
      attr_reader :cmd,:working_directory,:killProc
      def initialize params,&block
        @killProc=params[:killProc]
        @name=params[:name]
        @working_directory=params[working_directory]||"."
        if block_given?
          @cmd=block
        else
          raise "You Need to provide a block"
        end
      end 
    end
```

Comment: Ary you passing params as an `Array` instead of a `Hash` because `Array#[]` wants an integer. Also assuming it is a typo but ruby doesn't give out **clocks**

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure you're passing an array instead of a hash. You should call it like this:

```
RubyCommand.new({killProc:1,name:"test"})
```

Comment: Here is the part where I call RubyCommand. 

 ip = "{WAGO_IP}"
        port = "{WAGO_PORT}"
 step.cmd = Litu::RubyCommand.new("switch_wago_do") do |cmd, context|

Comment: @shube that will do it. You can't call it with a `String`. `String#[]` is also looking for an integer value. This answer is more or less correct other than the fact that the poster did not include the required block