# Ruby, no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer

Tags: ruby, implicit-conversion

yesterday I already asked you in "[no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer, Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38482973/no-implicit-conversion-of-symbol-into-integer-ruby)". I think you need further information to answer the question. That’s the reason, why I asked again. I updated my system from ruby 1.8.7 to the newer version of ruby 2.3.1p112.

When I want to run a test, I always get the error: **FATAL: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer**

Here is the code:

```
def element_switch_wago_do(step)
raise Rutema::ParserError, "Missing DO tag!" unless step.has_do?
raise Rutema::ParserError, "Missing DO value!" unless step.has_value?   
raise Rutema::ParserError, "Used DO value '#{step.value}' not supported [0||1 valid]!" unless ((0 == step.value.to_i) || (step.value.to_i == 1))

step.txt="Switch Wago DIGITAL output-pin #{step.do} to #{step.value}"
ip = "{WAGO_IP}"
port = "{WAGO_PORT}"
step.cmd = Litu::RubyCommand.new("switch_wago_do") do |cmd, context| 
    Litu::subst_template!(ip, context)
    Litu::subst_template!(port, context)
    Litu::subst_template!(step.do, context)    
    ModBus::TCPClient.new(ip, port.to_i) do |cl|
cl.with_slave(1) do |slave|
    slave.debug = false                         
    slave.write_single_coil(step.do.to_i,step.value.to_i)       end
end
end
end

class RubyCommand
    include Patir::Command
    attr_reader :cmd,:working_directory,:killProc
    def initialize params,&block
        @killProc=params[:killProc]
        @name=params[:name]
        @working_directory=params[:working_directory]||"."
        if block_given?
            @cmd=block
        else
            raise "You need to provide a block"
        end
    end

    #Runs the associated block
    def run context=nil
        @run=true
    begin
        t1=Time.now

        cmd = @cmd

        pwd = @working_directory
        p = Dir.pwd 
        puts "######: #{cmd}:"
        Litu::subst_template!(pwd, context)
        puts "before block in dir #{Dir.pwd}"

        Dir.chdir(pwd) do
            p = Dir.pwd 
            puts "in block in dir #{cmd}"
            @cmd.call(self, context)
            @status=:success
        end

        puts ":###### #{p}"

        rescue StandardError
            error << "\n#{$!.message}"
            error << "\n#{$!.backtrace}" if $DEBUG
            @status=:error
        ensure
            @exec_time=Time.now-t1
        end
        return @status
    end

    def kill!
        @killProc.call if @killProc
    end

    def to_s
        return @name
    end
end
```

If I comment the 3 lines in RubyCommand, I don’t get the error.

```
#@killProc=params[:killProc]
#@name=params[:name]
#@working_directory=params[:working_directory]||"."
```

The problem is something with array and hash. But I have no idea how to get this code running.

Comment: how do you create `RubyCommand` instance?

Comment: Instead of creating a new question you better modify your original question. (In meantime the other question is marked as duplicate).

Comment: in element_Switch_wago_do I create the instance like this:  RubyCommand.new("switch_wago_do") do |cmd, context|   and RubyCommand is a class defined in the same script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create `RubyCommand`instance like

```
Litu::RubyCommand.new("switch_wago_do")
```

and you have

```
def initialize(params, &block)
```

So `params` would be String equal `"switch_wago_do"`.
But you expect it to be Hash instance.

That is why commenting these strings solves problem.

```
@killProc=params[:killProc]
@name=params[:name]
@working_directory=params[:working_directory]||"."
```